# regex can't get special constructs (?=x) to work

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get a valid regex to use in java (java.util.regex) that validates the following format:

a number that has max 15 digits, of which 3 MAX digits may be decimal which are preceeded by a separator (,)

So, valid would be:

```
123456789012345  (15 digits, ok)
12345678901234,1
```

**[EDIT], these should also be valid:**

```
1234567890123,45
123456789012,345
```

So far i've come up with the following regex pattern:

```
Pattern = [0-9]{1,15}(\,[0-9]{1,3})?
```

This checks for a a range of 1 to 15 digits, following by an optional separator followed by another 3 digits. However, this doesnt check the total length of the input. With this regex, a value of 123456789012345,123 would be valid.

So, i thought i'd add an extra expression that checks the total length, and use the "(?=" construct to simulate the logical AND behaviour.

So i started with adding that to my existing regex expression as follows:

```
Pattern = (?= [0-9]{1,15}(\,[0-9]{1,3})?)
```

This however results in basically everything i throw at it failing, and i cant get it to work further. I don't see what i'm doing wrong here? After this works, i'd add another expression to check total length, something like (?=.{16}) i think.

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT]**
Realised you wanted to accept total length of 16 if there is a `,`, and also that you don't really need to use lookaround here, since you only have two cases. This works just fine:

```
public static boolean isValid(String input) {
    return input.matches("^(\\d{0,15}|\\d{1,12},\\d{1,3})$");
}
```

This returns valid if one of these is true

- input consists of 0-15 numbers *or*
- input consists of 1-12 numbers, followed by a `,`,  followed by 1-3 numbers

**[EDIT2]**

Ok, new try:

```
public static boolean isValid(String input) {
    return input.matches("^(\\d{0,15}|(?=.{3,16})\\d+,\\d{1,3})$");
}
```

This returns valid if one of these is true

- input consists of 0-15 numbers *or*
- input consists of 3-16 characters, consisting of at least one digit, followed by a `,`,  followed by 1-3 numbers

Comment: Edit by me: seems i wasnt specific enough in my description. I've added some examples of what may be valid. The "problem" is that there can be less than 3 digits, in that case the number before the digits can be longer than 12 characters.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one? play it on [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?31g39)

```
\d{12,15},?\d{3}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

```
    boolean a = Pattern.matches("\\d{15}|\\d{12},\\d{3}", "123456789012345");
    System.out.println(a);//true
    boolean b = Pattern.matches("\\d{15}|\\d{12},\\d{3}", "123456789012,345");
    System.out.println(b);//true
    boolean c = Pattern.matches("\\d{15}|\\d{12},\\d{3}", "1234567890123,456");
    System.out.println(c);//false
```

so your regEx is:

```
\d{15}|\d{12},\d{3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^\d{1,12}(?:\d{0,3}|\d{0,2},\d|\d{0,1},\d\d|,\d\d\d)$
```